# cordova soft input mode android

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

My cordova app consists of multiple html files each representing different views but keyboard is messing up the webview. On iOS I used ionic-plugin-keyboard’s

```
cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
```

to fix things but that only supports iOS. I could add

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
to AndroidManifest.xml which seems to fix it but I want this to apply to one view only. In other words, I want the keyboard to push up the views except one specific view.

I thought I could switch between these two

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN) 
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

depending on what view I am in but it looks like once setSoftInputMode is set it cannot be changed later? What’s the best way of solving this? Also, how would I prevent keyboard from pushing up a footer? (this behavior only appears in Android).

Sorry if my questions are confusing but I’ve been trying to solve these for few days now and keyboard is really frustrating me.

Answer (score 3):

I think I found the best way how to solve this issue. I made a cordova plugin.
When I wrote this question (30 minutes before this answer) I did not have any idea how to create a cordova plugin so I followed this great tutorial: http://www.mat-d.com/site/tutorial-creating-a-cordova-phonegap-plugin-for-android-app/.

Based on this one I imported `import android.view.WindowManager;` and than in the execute function in the `runOnUiThread` runnable I added this

```
if(action.equals("adjustPan"))
    cordova.getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
else if(action.equals("adjustResize"))  
    cordova.getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

Than based on how I call the function from javascript, it changes the input mode :)

I will add this plugin to github and add the link here

Edit: Here is the link from the plugin https://github.com/denkomanceski/windowSoftInputMode

All the instructions are there

Comment: Thats great but how do I add it to config.xml?

Comment: Ok this seems to kind of work: <plugin name="com.vertex.windowSoftInputMode" spec="https://github.com/denkomanceski/windowSoftInputMode.git"/> but now in my .ts-file it says cannot find windowSoftManager